# Facebook4j - Login / Oath

Tags: java, facebook, token

I'm having some doubts on how to authorize a user login on facebook on my program, so I can acess his informations like : friends, photos etc...

I've done some reasearches and I found this : https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j-oauth-example/blob/master/src/main/java/facebook4j/examples/signin/SignInServlet.java

But I cound't realize how this code works, how it will give-me the user token without the user login...

Some other codes using facebook4j can be found here: http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Thank you for your patience, Pedro.

Comment: You have to create a app in facebook and the javascript code onto your jsp or html file , there when the user visits that page it asks for login and after that you can get the access token using js

Comment: I've provided a minimal example on how to use facebook4j here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986045/facebook4j-api-search/20767233#20767233